# Visual Studio - cannot run dotnet command on Nuget Package Manager Console but ok in terminal

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am using Visual Studio in Macbook.

When I run `dotnet` in Nuget Package Manager Console, it shows:

> dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> dotnet
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (dotnet:String) [], CommandNotFoundException  
> FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
> ```

But I open terminal and run same command, it works.

How to solve it?